# How to convert ColorPicker.selectedColor to system.windows.media.color?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
ColorPicker _clpicker;
System.Windows.Media.Color c = _clpicker.SelectedColor;
```

**Error:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Color?' to
>   'System.Windows.Media.Color'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Comment: may be [WPF ColorPicker from wpf/xaml/toolkit binding to property error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495581/wpf-colorpicker-from-wpf-xaml-toolkit-binding-to-property-error) would be helpful

Comment: See the question mark in `System.Windows.Media.Color?`. Looks like you're dealing with a [Nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) here.

Answer (score 2):

Without more specific information, including details about the `ColorPicker` type you are using (there's no such built-in class in WPF…presumably you are using one of the many third-party options out there), it's impossible to know for sure what your problem is.

But based on the error message, it appears that the `SelectedColor` property is declared as `Nullable<Color>` (i.e. `Color?`), and of course just as the error says, while there is no implicit conversion from `Nullable<Color>` to `Color`, you can convert explicitly with a cast:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color c = (System.Windows.Media.Color)_clpicker.SelectedColor;
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Value` property:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color c = _clpicker.SelectedColor.Value;
```

Again, without more specifics it's unclear why the `SelectedColor` property is a nullable type. It's possible though that at the point in time you attempt this assignment, the value actually could be `null`. In which case, the compiler error is telling you something very important: **you've done nothing to handle the `null` case**.

Both of the above options will throw an exception if the `SelectedColor` property has the value `null`.

There are a number of ways to handle the `null` value, but the simplest is to let the `Nullable<T>` type do it for you:

```
System.Windows.Media.Color c = _clpicker.SelectedColor.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Then if the `SelectedColor` property has the value of `null`, the `c` variable will be assigned the default value for `System.Windows.Media.Color` (i.e. black). If you like, you can pass an alternative default value to the `GetValueOrDefault()` method, and it will return that value instead, if the original value is `null`.

Comment: @anthien Your `thank you very much` comment suggests that the user @PeterDuniho did solve your problem. You may want to mark his/her response as an `Answer` as it helps other readers, as well; otherwise, readers think that the issue is still unresolved.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Nicely explained a response to a question that was quite vague. Your response helped me (thank you) resolve a similar error while using `Extended WPF Toolkit`. The OP's  question also seems to related to that toolkit.